# Matching with andThen

Tags: scala

My (incomplete) code looks like this:

```
  def doSomething(name: String): { implicit request =>
    check(name).map {
      case Something() => Ok()
      case SomethingElse() => NoContent
    }
    .andThen {
      case r: Result => logger.info(s"Request finished with status ${r.header.status}")
    }
  }
```

I get an error like this:

```
[error] myfile.scala:39: fruitless type test: a value of type scala.util.Try[play.api.mvc.Result] cannot also be a play.api.mvc.Result
[error]       case r: Result => logger.info(s"Request finished with status ${r.header.status}")
```

How can I match that `Try`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to match on a `Try`, you need to match on its constructors, not what its constructors hold:

```
.andThen {
    case Success(r) =>
        logger.info(s"Request finished with status ${r.header.status}")

    case Failure(e) => // Handle failure
}
```